# execute a directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to execute a directory like this: './some_directory some_args'. In that some_directory there can be a script that grabs these some_args, processes them and passes them to a binary executable or other script located in the same directory. Basically, I want to run a script in some_director without specifying its name. There is got to be a default script to run I guess when doing './some_directory some_args' in bash or other shell. Thanks.

So I ended up using python and `__main__.py` script in this directory. You run it like this:

```
python ./directory
```

Comment: Executing a directory is simply not possible. What do you want to achieve that you cannot do by simply running a script by referencing the script?

Comment: Are we talking about `autorun` on a CD or DVD? Or is this directory on the hard disc.

Comment: So, in my directory there is a bunch of Python scripts. One script is the main one. I thought it would look shorter and nicer if you run ./directory instead of ./directory/script.py. You can think of a directory as an application in this case. If I'm not mistaking Mac OS does something like that.

Comment: Is 'directory' here the name of your app?

Comment: @user1806925: we don't do things like that in linux.

Comment: yes, directory can be the name of app

Comment: yes, this directory in on hard drive

Comment: MacOS X doesn't actually execute directories, either.  What's really happening is a program (like `open(1)`) is executing and taking the directory as its argument.  That program knows where to look in the directory for an executable that it then runs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a directory. Directories don't have default scripts. You need to put the path to the script on the command line.

Depending on why you're trying to do this, you could look at using a shell alias.

Comment: With `shopt autocd` you can use execute syntax to `cd` into a directory – but it doesn't let you run a script in the directory.

Comment: yes, but it needs to be portable and executed only from the directory where its directory is located: './app_name_dir'. So, ideally it is not desirable to make an alias

Comment: If you want to remove that restriction, maybe you could have the script cd to the proper place before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

python and `__main__.py` script in the directory. You run the directory like this: python `./directory`

Answer (score 0):

Executing a directory is nonsensical in Linux terms; you could perhaps set something up to fake it (e.g. autocd + prompt_command code), but it would just be confusing to any users who are familiar with Linux norms.

I would recommend instead that you install a script to start your application into a standard location, with the name of the app and no suffix. For example, the command `/usr/local/bin/myapp` just runs `/path/to/myapp/startscript.py`, and users can invoke it by simply typing `myapp`.

Comment: yes, but it needs to be portable and executed only from the directory where its directory is located: './app_name_dir'. So, ideally it is not desirable to put a reference script in bin

Comment: if the working directory matters, the script should cd.  none of the design of this app sounds very Linuxy at all.